# восстановление бд

Tags: java, mysql

как правильно запускать скрипт восстановление базы?

пробовал по разному:

1)     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u test -ptest testdb <  mydump.sql");

2)     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start mysqldump -u test -ptest testdb -rmydump.sql);

3)     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u test -ptest testdb mydump.sql);

4)

```
    String dbName = "testdb";
    String dbUser = "test";
    String dbPass = "test";

    String restorePath = txtFileDumpPath.getText();

    String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"mysql", dbName, "-u" + dbUser, "-p" 
    + dbPass, "-e", " source " + restorePath};

    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

    if (processComplete == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully restored from 
    SQL");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error at restoring");
    }
```

в основном получаю

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql": CreateProcess 
error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
```

указал в переменных среды путь к файлу mysql.exe но не помогает...

Comment: *Не удается найти указанный файл* Начните с указания непосредственно в операторе запуска полного пути. Как для клиента, так и для передаваемого ему файла дампа.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить полный путь к файлу можно создать `File` объект и выполнить

```
String restorePath = new File(txtFileDumpPath.getText()).getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: не думаю что дело именно в этом т.к. в другом методе возвращается абсолютПаз

Comment: в чем тогда дело, если неверный путь к файлу. Тогда получите файл как-то [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24841421/573032).